# IEnumerator to generics . 

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable

i have a few classes that i am trying to move to using generics

Class1: Curve

this class has the following code:

```
public class Curve : IEnumerable

  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator(); // Calls non-interface method
    }

  public RTRatePointEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new RTRatePointEnumerator(_hash);
    }
```

Class 2:

```
  public class CurvePointEnumerator : IEnumerator
```

what is the recommended conversion of these two classes to using generics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the type being returned from the enumerator.  but I'm going to guess based on the names it's RTRatePoint and CurvePoint.  I would change the code to be the following

```
class Curve: IEnumerable<RTRatePoint> {
  IEnumerator<RTRatePoint> IEnumerable<RTRatePoint>.GetEnumerator() { 
    return GetEnumerator();
  }
  public RTRatePointEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
    return new RTRatePointEnumerator(_hash);
  }
}

class CurvePointEnumerator : IEnumerator<CurvePoint>
```

One item that may trip you up is that IEnumerator<T> additionally implements IDisposable so CurvePointEnumerator and RTRatePointEnumerator will need to have a Dispose method added. Likely though this method can be pretty much empty.   Reason being if you weren't disposing anything before, there's no need to now.

```
void IDispose.Dispose() {
  // Nothing to see here
}
```

Comment: what would i put in the dispose method here . .

Comment: Unless you've actually *got* a finalizer, you don't need to put a call to SuppressFinalize.

Answer (score 0):

`IEnumerable<T> and IEnumerator<T>`

gah, it swallowed my code